# I'm trying to give notification by Firebase cloud function, but my code doesn't give any notification

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have done authentication trigger, it's working fine. If someone delete their account I need to send to notification "this user deleted his account (email)" like that. Here is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

//initialize the app
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

const ref = admin.database().ref()

//create user account function
exports.createUserAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const uid = event.data.uid
    const email = event.data.email

    const newUserRef = ref.child(`/UserNotify/${uid}`)
    return newUserRef.set({
        email: email
    })
})

//delete user account function
exports.cleanupUserData = functions.auth.user().onDelete(event => {
    const uid = event.data.uid
    const userRef = ref.child(`/UserNotify/${uid}`)
    return userRef.update({isDeleted: true}) 
})

function sendNotification() {

    console.log("Successfully sent");

    var payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "User get deleted",
            body: "sample@gmail.com"
        }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToDeveice(payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a typing error 
`admin.messaging().sendToDevice()` and not `sendToDeveice`

check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

Comment: i checked them but im unable to apply them to my senario can u help me with that

Comment: I am assuming you want to send the user an email, 
have a look at this example: 
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js#L58

Comment: no i need give push notification to other users that use my app "some one (email) delete his account" like that

Comment: based on the your implementation, you would use an array of your users registration tokens from their devices, probably stored in your database and send them the deleted email from the onDelete event.